# How can my IOS app know when the multitask bar is shown?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiapplicationdelegate

For the most part my app handles this action with no issues. However, at one point I have a sound looping playback and if the home button is double tapped to open the multitask bar, the sound just continues playing until the multitask bar is closed and it ends its sequence.

I would expect there to be a UIApplicationDelegate method that is called for this action, but I can't find any documentation of it.

Comment: In most games, when the multitasking bar opens, the game auto-pauses. Maybe look for something relevant to iOS games and how the pause menu works.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application fires when the multitask bar is shown.